# How to print length of memory and buffer?

Tags: c, memory, stack, size, buffer

I need to print size of memomry and buffer?

is their another way?

```
size_t len;
len = strlen(input);
printf("******************len is : %d\n", len)
```

I have just edited my question where 'input' is actually 'buffer'

Comment: Is `input` a null-terminated byte-string? Then that's the usual way to get its length. ***However*** note that [the `strlen` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) returns a value of type `size_t` (as your variable is) and the correct format to print a `size_t` is `"%zu"`  (if you see e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)).

Comment: You didn't show the definition of `input`, but if it's an array, like `char input[1024]`, then `sizeof input` would be the size of the buffer, which would not equal `strlen(input)`, the length of the string. But if it's a pointer (`char *input`), you cannot (portably) get the size of the area of memory pointed to by it.

Comment: @3294833840_ `printf("buffer: <%s>, len: %zu\n", input, len);`  Is there something more than that that you seek?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom malloc method, which comes from redis

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* zmalloc(size_t size) {
    void* ptr = malloc(size + sizeof(size_t));
    *((size_t*)ptr) = size;
    return ptr + sizeof(size_t);
}

size_t zmalloc_size(void* ptr) {
    void* real_ptr = ptr - sizeof(size_t);
    return *((size_t*)real_ptr);
}

int main() {
    void* ptr = zmalloc(100);
    printf("%zu", zmalloc_size(ptr));
}
```